# I am unable to include "code" into this system as part of a question. Anything I put into the "Body"

Tags: android

For example, I only have one "body" but have a description like:

I can understand that a non-BLE device will not respond to the BLE Client device (Android) using StartDiscovery but should respond to a Scan request. I believe that the AdaFruit is responding to a discovery event because I am getting discovery responses to devices within range with the Android device app in the Settings/Connections/Bluetooth display. This includes the Adafruit BLE device. Again, I believe this means that the problem is on the Android side. I have searched everything I can find but most of the information I get is years old. I have focused in on something called LeScanCallback and/or LeDeviceListAdapter as the potential problem. I can't even tell is my callback is being triggered. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

but when I try to insert a code block this system won't let me post the question. I have seen many other questions where the poster actually has different input blocks for the manifest, xms, and main Java script, but I don't see anything like that.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66405672/edit) your post to include 'code' you'll have to use [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on your text.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I had the formatting wrong. I needed to manually insert 4 spaces in front of every line, and use the "Code here". That will teach me for reading the instructions too fast! Thanks for the comment from Morrison Chang that put me in the right direction.